# "Stripe is not defined" error - call of function before script is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I think I have a problem with a script that doesn't load (or load too early).

I try to implement [Stripe library](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server) for paiement. For that, I have to include a script  before using Stripe functions in my code.
I added the given script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/", in my public folder, in index.html in the header as follow:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I created an empty app, with only call of Stripe. here is App.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(){
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXX');
    // I will use stripe variable later. But for now I have an error with previous line
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
          <Button 
                  className= "btn-xlBook"
                  variant="primary"
                  onClick={this.handleClick}>
                  OK
          </Button>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
export default App
```

But when I make a yarn start, I have the error **'Stripe' is not defined  no-undef**.

I don't understand, I call the script in the header, but the behavior is as if the script wasn't loaded yet.

Do you know how to solve it ? I I add a script in the header of index.html, it should load before the app, isn't it ?

Comment: try to use the npm package instead on importing the js file in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't import `Stripe` anywhere. Like you do with `Button` for example. Check out [React Stripe Elements](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements) for one example of how to use Stripe in React.

Answer (score 1):

Use npm package of stripe instead and import it. Add the import statement and use the wrapper in your index.js

```
import {StripeProvider} from 'react-stripe-elements';


<StripeProvider apiKey="pk_test_12345">
      <MyStoreCheckout />
 </StripeProvider>
```

and then in your console install the package:

```
npm install --save react-stripe-elements
```

or

```
yarn add react-stripe-elements
```

Comment: Perhaps update your answer to use `yarn` since he's not using `npm`?

Comment: @Shivendu Amale : 'stripe' isn't for server side use ? I have the following error using it "__webpack_require__(...).createServer is not a function" and first answer  I see says that it is for server side

Comment: Ok got it. Its `react-stripe-elements` for react. `Stripe` module is serrver side. I'll change my answer